# VSCode Marks Less-Than-Sign In HTML Attribute Red

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, alpine.js

I noticed that VSCode marked a less-than-sign in an HTML attribute red, I wonder what's the problem with that?

[image]

I'm using [Alpine.js](https://alpinejs.dev/), which lets you write JS code in HTML attributes, but it should all be legal HTML (see also [here](https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine/discussions/3128)) so I wonder if this actually against the HTML spec or just the opinion of VSCode.

Comment: Inside an Alpine.js directive, you can write regular JS code, so the less-then sign is completely valid. My guess that the syntax highlighter does not know about Alpine.js so it tries to parse the string inside the attribute causing the issue. You can just ignore it, or you can avoid it by creating a component for the complex cases, so you only have to write the callable method's name in the attribute.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment!  Feel free to post as answer, I don't think there is much more info to add.

Comment: But I still wonder what it parses exactly.  I has also no 'problem' with `>`, just `<` gets marked red.  It's not necessarily an Alpine.js thing, one could also get creative otherwise and do something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/monc2y6p/3/) (also note that JSFiddles syntax highlighter has no problem with it).